# Read voltage is outside of operating range

Tags: programming, atmel

I wanted to program my AtXMega16A4U with an Atmel ICE Basic, using Atmel Studio, but even if the supply voltage on the µC is at the perfect range (3.3 V) I get the error "Read voltage is outside of operating range: 0.8V" (Voltage does not vary). What can I do to find the problem, and how can I fix that?

Comment: You mnight have more luck asking this on *AVR freaks* forum.

Comment: Check that the ISP connector i correctly placed, if I remember correctly you will get this error when the programmer (Atmel ICE/STK500 etc...) is not properly connected.
You should also maybe check the connections all the way from ISP connector to µC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was the wire itself which was internally broken.